# Insert lines in a SVG image

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, highcharts

I want to insert a line in a document of type SVG. I can not find elements like normal HTML with Jquery. The line I want to show is described in the following image. There will be a set of lines as the user clicks on the map areas.

https://www.screencast.com/t/UxnsEou6OQI

I want to draw this line when the percent value appears. That is. When I click on the area. The element to insert into the DOM is as follows.

Element to be inserted into the DOM to draw lines.

```
<svg>
   <line x1="90" y1="70" x2="140" y2="90" style="stroke:#fff;stroke-width:1"/>
</svg>
```

Where it is the XML file for SVG image. In this file you can find the  tag

[Testarea](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gu5eHKztWYSOrirSKEbzVxiR53LDQCWQ)

I have a function (jquery) on my code that shows a section when I click in an area #Tolltip. I just want to add in this function a part to add the lines in a specific position.

This is the switch of my function.

```
         witch (this.id) {
                  case "Porto":
                    //I want to add here --->       
                    $('#Tooltip').insertBefore("<svg><line x1='90' y1='70' x2='140' y2='90' style='stroke:#fff;stroke-width:1'/></svg>");
                    // this is to set the attributes of the first "g" inside the "svg ->
                    tt.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(0,-350)');
                    break;
                  case 1:
                    alert('1');
                    break;
                  default:
                    alert('default');
                }
```

Resume. I want to insert two  above the first element "g" inside of one "svg"

A little confusing I know :(

Comment: Can you update your question with a simple [mcve] please?  It would help us understand your situation better. For instance, what type of element is `#Tooltip`?

Comment: If you're using Highcharts you can easily add a line using SVGRenderer (see: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path)

Comment: Sorry. I´m not using highchart. I'm only working with SVG image. I´m gonna teel better what I intend.

Comment: I update the post with Testarea file to see the structure of the XML file to SVG image. Many thanks :)

Comment: Ok. I think I've been able to solve the problem. I changed the file and added the <line> tags. Now in the function, I setAtributes to this element and added the coordinates. I think it's working.